# IonicFreamwork React, handleRefresh and custom fetch hook

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile application in ionic framework. When I pull the page up, I perform the refresh process. I can find out how to integrate my useFetch hook into handleRefresh when I refresh the page.

```
function handleRefresh(event: CustomEvent<RefresherEventDetail>) {
setTimeout(() => {
  event.detail.complete();
}, 1000); }

  const { data: test_allProjectData, loading: test_projectLoading } = useFetch<IAllProjectData>('/api/projects', "get", user?.token);
```